# Forget Content Before Pause in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pause

I am using beamer

and I am drawing some figures on an image, which should appear sequentially on the image.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}

    \begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}

            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{1.png}};
            \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
                \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
                \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
                \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
                \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.2,0.84) rectangle (0.1,0.95); \pause
                \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.52,0.7) rectangle (0.85,0.36); \pause
                \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.09,0.84) rectangle (0.294,0.16); \pause
                \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.12,0.15) rectangle (0.294,0.06); \pause
                \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.36,0.7) rectangle (0.48,0.31); \pause
                \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.04,0.94) rectangle (0.85,0.2);

            \end{scope}
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

The problem: after a new figure appears on the image, I want the old one to fade out.

How could this be done ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want animated fading, `beamer` can achieve this by creating multiple slides on which the objects have slightly different colors, and showing those in rapid succession (like a flip-book, only works in presentation mode). This could generate a pdf with many pages, which I'm not sure you want. Furthermore, fading to invisible may be problematic. The current version of beamer (3.36) does not support "true" transparency, so instead fakes it by blending an object's color with the frame background color. This will cause problems in your case because you're drawing shapes atop a figure. In trying to make the objects transparent `beamer` will actually make them white (to match the background), regardless of the figure colors.

If you wish the objects to disappear completely after you've drawn them, you can use `\visible` to specify the slides on which each object should be visible.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \visible<1>{\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.2,0.84) rectangle (0.1,0.95);}
        \visible<2>{\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.52,0.7) rectangle (0.85,0.36);}
        \visible<3>{\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.09,0.84) rectangle (0.294,0.16);}
        \visible<4>{\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.12,0.15) rectangle (0.294,0.06);}
        \visible<5>{\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.36,0.7) rectangle (0.48,0.31);}
        \visible<6>{\draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.04,0.94) rectangle (0.85,0.2);}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use `\temporal` to define the appearance before, on, and after a given slide. In the following, `\colorize` is defined to be invisible before the given slide, red on the given slide, and 35% black thereafter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\colorize<#1>{%
    \temporal<#1>{\invisible<-#1>}{\color{red}}{\color{black!35}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }

        \colorize<1>{\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.2,0.84) rectangle (0.1,0.95);}
        \colorize<2>{\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.52,0.7) rectangle (0.85,0.36);}
        \colorize<3>{\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.09,0.84) rectangle (0.294,0.16);}
        \colorize<4>{\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.12,0.15) rectangle (0.294,0.06);}
        \colorize<5>{\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.36,0.7) rectangle (0.48,0.31);}
        \colorize<6>{\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.04,0.94) rectangle (0.85,0.2);}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]